# Semantic UI Sidebar Issue ( Sidebar separating line is not visible)

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have Home, Contact and About menu in sidebar and I want a separation line between these menus.
In semantic UI react showing these separations but on screen not showing.
My React code is below

```js
import "./styles.css";

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Sidebar, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'
export class SidebarComponent extends Component {
  state = { activeItem: 'Home' }
  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })
  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar
        as={Menu}
        animation='overlay'
        icon='labeled'
        inverted
        vertical
        visible
        width='small' >
        <Menu.Item
          name='Home'
          active={activeItem === 'Home'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick} 
        >
        Home
        </Menu.Item>
        
        <Menu.Item
          name='Contact'
          active={activeItem === 'Contact'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick} 
        >
          Contact
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item
          name='About'
          active={activeItem === 'About'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick} 
        >
           About
        </Menu.Item> 
        </Sidebar>
      </div>
    )}}
    export default SidebarComponent;
```

After running my code I got this type of output ( Output image below)
Current Output

[image]

But I want this type of output (below)
Required Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 ways in which you can add a divider-

1. Using semantic-ui-react
2. Using Vanilla CSS

---

1. **Using semantic-ui-react**

import Divider from semantic-ui-react.

```js
import { Sidebar, Menu, Divider } from 'semantic-ui-react'
```

And add this line of code after the first and second Menu.Item

```js
<Divider fitted />
```

2. **Using Vanilla CSS**

in styles.css add -

```css
.ui.vertical.menu .item{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

this will add border-bottom for every item.